# Removing Dudplicate Rows based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which contains duplicates values according to four columns (SFDC_ID and left_side and right_SFDC_ID and right_side   and similairity):

Right now SFDC_ID and right_SFDC_ID are duplicating in the following way:

```
SFDC_ID left_side   right_SFDC_ID   right_side  similairity

0013s00000vEVuwAAG  Hague Quality Water 0013s00000vEW72AAG  Hague Quality Waters    0.99023304
0013s00000vEW72AAG  Hague Quality Waters    0013s00000vEVuwAAG  Hague Quality Water 0.99023304
```

If you look closely, the SFDC_ID of row 1 is the same as right_SFDC_ID of row 2.

How would I drop the second-row using pandas?

Comment: i'd suggest you format ur data a bit better, cos at the moment one cant tell if Haque quality waters is a column on its own or combined with 0013...

Comment: Format it better in Stackoverflow? I believe I updated this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
# compares which is greater based on alphabetical order and makes a bool series
mask = df['SFDC_ID'] < df['right_SFDC_ID'] 

# creates a new column checking True vs False, 

#if mask is true item in df['SFDC_ID'] is selected else item in df['right_SFDC_ID'] is selected

df['col1'] = df['SFDC_ID'].where(mask, df['right_SFDC_ID'])

#same as above but a column for df['right_SFDC_ID']
df['col2'] = df['right_SFDC_ID'].where(mask, df['SFDC_ID'])

# checks for duplicates in `col1` and `col2` and removes last duplicate
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Comment: could you explain what this exactly does?

Comment: matches_df['SFDC_ID'] < matches_df['right_SFDC_ID'] What does this exactly do?

Comment: Did you find my commented answer helpful?

Comment: Its not working for me - I am still finding the same issue

Comment: Based on the example you've given, I understand that you want the second row to be removed because 'SFDC_ID' or 'right_SFDC_ID' are the same. The lines that I've put above does exactly that. The code checks if both of those columns duplicate (in any order) and keeps only the first occurence.

Comment: I posted the question in more depth over here. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467185/dataframe-rows-are-matching-with-each-other-in-tf-idf-cosine-similarity-i

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the rows and drop rows where the previous rows value matches

```
for index,row in df[1::].iterrows():
    prev_SFDC_ID = df.iloc[index-1]['SFDC_ID'] #get prev SFDC_ID value
    if row['right_SFDC_ID'] == prev_SFDC_ID: 
        df.drop(index=index, inplace=True)
```